# Get Data From FreePBX Server in Asp.Net C# application

Tags: asp.net, pbx

I need to get all the data from FreePBX Server like Call logs, Directories, Users.... into my ASP.NET Application so what should I do? I found Asterisk but can't understand how to work with that. Is there any other API or Asterisk tutorial?